# Creating a list of node-options in different node

Tags: entities, nodes

I am looking for a way to list nodes in a different node. Not sure how to explain this, so I will do it with an example.

Let's say I'm for example making a website for a Tennis tournament, this is not the real purpose, so if you have a different solution for this, it's probably not what I need, I want to achieve what I'll say in this example:

I have the following nodes:

- Player
- Match

In player I have:

- Player name
- Player age
- Player ranking
- etc...

In the node match, I have a few settings, including:

- Player 1
- Player 2

What I want to achieve is that in the node "match" I can choose 2 players from the node "player". In the list it shows the player name, however, I should be able to get the extra information as well when rendering the match node.

Any ideas if a certain module excists that could help me out?

Thank you very much!

---

**Edit 22/07/2014:**

As an addition, I would also like a different list to inherit his items depending on a previous selected item.

So for example I have 3 nodes:

- Car
- Brand
- Model

The first thing that I would do is:
I make different brands as "Brand" nodes content:

- BMW
- Mercedes
- Volvo
- ...

Afterwards I make a Model. In model I make the models
- 'Z4' => And in the list I choose "Brand: BMW"
- 'S60' => And in the list I choose "Brand: Volvo"
- 'V70' => And in the list I choose "Brand: Volvo"
- ...

Now I want my third node "car" to be for example for a seller of cars.
So the seller sells a car. He makes a car node and enters the following information:

- Buyer: Person A
- Address: Address X
- Age: 99
- Licenseplate: 1 XXX 999
- Brand: ....
- Model: ....

So what I'm trying to achieve is that the seller has a list of all brands.
If he chooses brand "Volvo" for example, then the Model list should appear and show all models for the chosen brand.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're wanting can be accomplished with views.  You may need to add some fields to make the context work for your needs.

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer and provide details.

Comment: I don't think a view is what I need.
It's not the result that is viewable that I want to change, what I need is a list when creating the node

So, with the example of the cars:
1.I make brands of cars.
2. I make models where I pick a brand from a selection list (based on the brands made in brand node)
3. I make a new car & choose a brand from a selection list, then when I pick that brand, the selection list for models should be filled up.

I doubt that this would be possible with views, as it's the backend I want to have like this, not the forend. And I expect I need ajax to fill second list.

Comment: If I'm correct, then your idea was to make the nodes by typing in the model name in the input field twice, and then having a view that combines the 2. That's not a problem, I already have a complete setup which shows the result correctly to the site visitors. What I want however, is that content providers do not have to type it, but choose it from a list, therefor they can't misstype it.
That I can do by making the field a list, and adding possible input's in the list, however, I want to make this list dynamic, by making it load the names of another nodetype.

Comment: Maybe Taxonomy with hierarchy is more in line with what you're looking for.

https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select

Comment: I already use that, however that isn't what I'm looking for. It's really something with AJAX that I need, but I suppose there's no module available yet, so I'll have to check to make it myself I'm afraid.

Taxonomy would be great, if I only needed 1 level. But I need multiple levels, where 1 list box inherits it's data depending on the earlier chosen data from another list.

Imagine a database with all tennis players in the world, that would be a way too long list. would be better if you first choose the country, then get only players from that country to choose from.

Comment: Here's a couple more that might work:

Field Conditional States
https://www.drupal.org/project/field_conditional_state

Dynamic Dependant Fields
https://www.drupal.org/project/ddf

Comment: That might indeed just do the trick, I will try these out later today and see if they are the solution I need, thank you very much!